# Which RxJava operator to make it simpler

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, reactive-programming

I found a way to make it simpler instead of using two `flatmap` and filter

```
val a = Observable.just(false)
val b = Observable.just(true)

val x = Observable.just(Unit)

x.flatMap { a }
 .filter { !it }
 .flatMap { b }
 .filter { it }
 .subscribe {
  // a must be false and b must be true
 }
```

I want to filter so subscribe only invoke when a is false and b is true, the code above is correct but I want to find a way to make it more simple; I try to use concat but I don't know why I can't use it...

Comment: What are you trying to do? with that snippet of code is difficult to help. Are you trying to filter an element based on other two boolean elements?

Comment: I updated my question, yes Im trying to filter an element based on 2 boolean element and want to ask is there any way to make it more simple instead using 2 flatMap and filter operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can accomplish that. Choosing a `simpler` solution is opinion-based and depends on **how you want to handle items emitted by `a` and `b`**. While the latter one might not be that apparent when testing `Observable.just`s, when it comes to more sophisticated `Observables` you could see the difference.

***In your example `b` is subscribed to only if `a` has the correct value. Was that intended?***

For me the cleaner solution would be to `zip` them and compare the contents "together". But this expects items from both `Observable` before possibly emitting an item.

```
Observable.zip(a, b, BiFunction { a, b -> Pair(a, b) })
    .filter { !it.first && it.second }
    .subscribe {
        // a must be false and b must be true     
    }
```

---

**Edit:**

*To give you an example of a different way of accomplishing this, here's an example without `filter`:*

```
Observable.zip(a.takeWhile { !it }, b.takeWhile { it }, BiFunction { _, _ -> Unit })
    .subscribe {
        // a must be false and b must be true
    }
```

(remember that they all have different expectations on `a` and `b`)

Comment: Yes b is subscribed only if a has correct value.. your explanation and example is great for me.. thankss